# Adding events to control dynamically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am creating a web control by addin the html in the code behind, like this:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
Dim myDiv As HtmlGenericControl = Me.theContainer

sb.Append("<table width='100%'  cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='border:0px;'>" & vbCrLf)
sb.Append(" <tr class='mainRow1'>" & vbCrLf)
sb.Append("<td  align='left'  style='border:0px solid white;'>Main Menu</td>" & vbCrLf)
sb.Append("<td>" & vbCrLf)
sb.Append("<asp:Label ID='Label1' runat='server' Text='Label'></asp:Label>" & vbCrLf)
sb.Append("</td>" & vbCrLf)
sb.Append("<td  align='right' style='border:0px solid white;'>Sort By: Id | Name</td>" & vbCrLf)
sb.Append("</tr>" & vbCrLf)
sb.Append("</table>" & vbCrLf)

myDiv.InnerHtml = sb.ToString
```

This will generate the html for the table in the codebehind then inject it into the specified DIV element. My question is, if I create a control in this manner, how do I add an event that will fire a method in my codebehind? For example, if I want to create a image button I would do it this way in the code:

```
<asp:ImageButton CommandArgument='<%# (Container.DataItem.objectValue) %>'            
ID='ImageButton1' runat='server' OnCommand='Button1_Click' ImageUrl='~/images/folder.gif' />
```

but in the code behind I would do this:

```
sb.Append("<input type='image' name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$importWizard1$folderControl1$folderRepeater$ctl04$ImageButton" & myCounter & "'")
sb.Append(" id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_importWizard1_folderControl1_folderRepeater_ctl04_ImageButton" & myCounter & "'")
sb.Append(" src='images/folder.gif' style='border-width:0px;'  />" & vbCrLf)
```

My question is, considering that I am generating the control on the server, how do I add an "onCommand" event that would fire a specific method on the server?  I'm not looking to just cause the page to reload.  This functionality is in a user control (ascx file) that is in a update pannel.  I just want the update pannel to post back, not the whole page.  When I view the source of a image button, or any button, with an ONCommand event, it is acutally not even in teh code behind.

Any help would be great.  Oh, I am developing with Visual studio 2005

Thanks
jason

if I try to add a server control like this:

```
Dim img As New ImageButton
img.Command = New CommandEventHandler(AddressOf Button1_Click)

img.ID = "button-" & item.directoryName & "-" & item.objectValue
Dim newSb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
Dim tw As StringWriter = New StringWriter(newSb)
Dim hw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(tw)
img.RenderControl(hw)
```

the "img.Command "  gives me an error (blue squigley line) saying "Public Event Command(sender as object, e as webcontrols.commandEventArgs) is an event and cannot be called directly.  use a raise event statement to raise an event"

```
Dim img As New ImageButton()
img.ID = "button-" & item.directoryName & "-" & item.objectValue
img.ImageUrl = "images/folder.gif"
AddHandler img.Click, AddressOf img_Click

Dim newSb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
Dim tw As StringWriter = New StringWriter(newSb)
Dim hw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(tw)

img.RenderControl(hw)
sb.Append(tw.ToString)

Protected Sub img_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ImageClickEventArgs)
    ...
End Sub
```

Although this seem to render fine (when I view the source) the method is never actually called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i figured it out and wanted to post in case anyone else is trying to do this:

1. on the client side, add this javascript function:

   ```
    function UpdPanelUpdate(value){   
    var obj = document.getElementById("<%= text.ClientID %>");   
    obj.value=value;  
     __doPostBack("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$importWizard1$folderControl1$button","");
    }
   ```
2. on the client side, add these controls:

   ```
     <asp:TextBox ID="text" runat="server" style="display:none;"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" CommandArgument="" style="display:none;"/>
   ```
3. On the client page, add this updatedate panel with triggers:

   ```
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"  UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
       <div runat="server" id="theContainer" style="position:relative; border:1px solid grey; width:51em; height:28.8em; overflow:auto; align:left;"> 
           <asp:TextBox  runat="server" ID="currentIdTb" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>     
       </div>
   </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="button" EventName="Click" />
     </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
   ```
4. in the codebehind, add this handler:

   ```
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
     'code here
    end sub
   ```
5. last, in the codebehind, add an onclick even to call the js function.

   ```
      sb.Append("<input type='image' name='b" & myCounter & "'")
           sb.Append(" id='b" & myCounter & "'")
           sb.Append(" src='images/folder.gif' style='border-width:0px;' ")
           sb.Append(" onClick=""UpdPanelUpdate('" & item.objectValue & "')""  />" &   vbCrLf)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably possible to do this they way you are doing it but I wouldn't recommend it. The key is knowing the difference between HTML controls and Server controls.

To add the event you need to build up server controls and then add them to you div - something like this (this is C# not VB but you get the idea)

```
Table table = new Table();
TableRow row = new TableRow();
TableCell cell = new TableCell();

ImageButton img = new ImageButton();
img.Command += new CommandEventHandler(img_Command);

cell.Controls.Add(img);
row.Controls.Add(cell);
table.Controls.Add(row);

myDiv.Controls.Add(table);
```

**Edit**

As per your comments I think the problem is that in VB you register handlers different than in C# - you need to look at AddHandler (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93(v=vs.80).aspx) so something like this is what you need

```
AddHandler img.Command, AddressOf Button1_Click
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I've tried creating a server control but I dont have the option to add ".Command". Intelisense only has .CommandName (a string) and .commandArguement. If it makes a difference, im using visual studio 2005

Comment: ImageButton has had a Command event since .NET 1.1 (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.command(v=vs.71).aspx) - are you sure you are creating an ImageButton not an Image? Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: ill append my original question

Comment: I appened my question to show what i did to add the control.  Intelisense doesnt even have the option for "Command".  If i type it in, i get the error I was talkin about in the question

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I added the event handler as you suggested but the even is still not raised and the method is never called (i have a break point on the method.  Ill append my code to display what I wrote

Comment: I think looking at your code the problem is that you are using RenderControl() to add to page I don't think this will work. Add a Placeholder to the page where you want the ImageButton and then call Placeholder.Controls.Add(img)

Comment: do you know of anyway to keep this stictly in the codebehind? I need to generate these controls (its in a loop so its not just one control) on the fly and i dont know how I would create the rest of the objects I'm adding in the codebehind while having the image control in a repeater.  And, even when I add it to a place holder, the method is never fired.  it causes a post back but the event that I have attached never get hit